# Symbol which looks like an underscore with small lines on each end?

Tags: symbols

What is the LaTeX symbol, as well as the actual name for this symbol which looks like an underscore with small bars (serifs?) on each end?

[image: LaTeX character]

Comment: Please see the [link here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character). DeTeXify recognizes this.`\textvisiblespace`

Comment: it is most commonly accessed by using `\verb*`  or the `verbatim*` environment in which spaces are rendered that way.